# Microsoft CRM 2011 change url for different organizations

Tags: iis-7, dynamics-crm

I have Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 with minimal servers (two servers: CRM and SQL). And I create two organizations (org1 and org2). Now I can access to organizations:

```
http://servername/org1 

http://servername/org2
```

I want to have access like this:

http://org1.domain.com and 
http://org2.domain.com

Can you please help me with this, what I must to change.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a simple change. The hosting/deployment way has to change.

[IFD - Internet Facing Deployment](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/113817) is what you are looking for.

```
IFD Configuration on CRM Server

Open the Deployment Manager.
Right-click Microsoft Dynamics CRM , and then click Configure Internet-Facing Deployment
```

[image]

Comment: We prefer answers to be usable on their own; for that, they need to have more than just a buzzword and a link.

Comment: IFD is a term every Dynamics CRM guy can understand.. OP was waiting for 4 years to get this answer :) not even a single comment..to direct him to MSDN or atleast to SO..